# Layout is getting distracted?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am making an Android app, whose main.xml file is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_full">

        <Button android:id="@+id/nxt_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="360dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>

        <com.broov.player.DrawView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawingSurface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my emulator it's working fine, but when the device or emulator resolution changes the layout became distracted. I need the layout to be universal for every machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify the relationship of components in your layout : toLeftOf or toRightOf.